# Converting comma separated string to list, then display list in Django template

Tags: python, django, list

I'm trying to take an input that is a comma separated string value, store those items in a list for temporary display and use in a template. I'm currently having trouble storing each comma separated string value in a list, then displaying that list in a template.

A user inputs something similar into a database ModelForm field (without the quotes):

example input from a `ModelForm`

```py
inputs = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then the user would input something to the effect of

"length_ft,depth_in,width_in"

minus the quotes.

The following then sort-of works in the template:

```html
{% for i in inputs_list %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of displaying a list of list items, it simply lists each letter of each list item separately. I realize why, because I am stripping out commas, but then I'm trying to append the blank list with each csv item.

I don't understand how to get items out of the input string to a list, then to display in the template.

#### views.py

```py
def test_formula(request, formula_id):
    formula = Formula.objects.get(id=formula_id)
    inputs_list = []
    for inputs in formula.inputs:
        strip = inputs.strip(",")
        inputs_list.append(strip)

    context = {'formula': formula, 'inputs_list': inputs_list}
    return render(request, 'formulas/test_formula.html', context)
```

#### formulas/test_formula.html

(this just breaks up each character into it's own item)

```html
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

{% for i in inputs_list %}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

formulas\urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('test_formula/<int:formula_id>', views.test_formula, name='test_formula'),
]
```

Comment: I just updated hopefully it is more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a string of comma separated values such as `"length_ft,depth_in,width_in"`, update your code to:

```
def test_formula(request, formula_id):
    formula = Formula.objects.get(id=formula_id)

    context = {'formula': formula, 'inputs_list': formula.inputs.split(",")}
    return render(request, 'formulas/test_formula.html', context)
```

Basically, you need to us the `str` method [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which returns a list of the words in the string, using the parameter that you pass as the delimiter string.

I would also suggest changing the variable `i` to `input` in the for in the template.

Comment: This totally solved it. I don't understand though - why would this work when passing the formula.inputs.split(",") through the context but not when iterating over the inputs_list variable the way I show it in the views.py above?

Comment: @KevinW, I just added a further explanation. I hope it clarifies your doubts. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: @KevinW, I think the problem in your code is also that you are using the method `strip` which returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

Comment: AHA! I think that is it! Thank you so much. I've spent so much time trying to figure this out!